# ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my trending.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tmdb_movies/utils/text.dart';

class TrendingMovies extends StatelessWidget {
  
  final List trending ;
  const TrendingMovies({Key? key, required this.trending}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,

        children: [
          modified_text( size: 25, text: 'Trending Movies',color: Colors.white,),
          SizedBox(height: 10,),
          Container(height: 270,
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: trending.length,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                return InkWell(
                  onTap: (){

                  },
                  child: Container(
                    width: 140,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          height: 200,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(image: DecorationImage(
                            image: NetworkImage(
                              'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' +trending[index]['poster_path']
                            )
                          )),
                        ),
                        Container(child: modified_text(text: trending[index]['title'] != null?
                        trending[index]['title']:'loading', color: Colors.white,size: 14,),)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am new to flutter dev.I am building IMDB movie app in flutter. I am using IMDB movie api. In this code block i am trying to see the trending movies for this i declare a List called trending. But after running i gets error. How can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It means that the trending list has not been initialized, and it's null. You have to initialize it first. I would recommend to make the widget stateful and then, in its initState, fill the trending list.